# Accessing variables that are updated inside of a thread while the thread is running

Tags: python, multithreading, progress-bar, pysimplegui

I'm trying to use several functions both with PySimpleGui and by themselves in another script, but I'm trying to have a progress bar update in the gui, without needing a gui/window when i'm running those same functions from a stand along script (where I might only get feedback or print statements from the terminal)

I thought threading would be the answer, where I run my functions in a thread, and then let the gui monitor the status of some global progress bar variables and update the progress bars as those variables are changed. I'm not sure if this is possible, or if I'm just not implementing it correctly. Here's an idea of what I'm working with, where I might have multiple progress bars for nested for loops

```
import threading
import time
import PySimpleGUI as sg

#some global variables
progBar = {'text': 3*[''], 'max': 3*[1], 'current': 3*[0], 'used': 3*[False]}
update_progBar = False

def general_long_function():
    global update_progBar
    update_progBar = True

    progBar['used'][0] = True
    progBar['used'][1] = True
    progBar['max'][0] = 1
    progBar['text'][0] = 'Do Top loop'

    progBar['max'][1] = 10
    for i in range(10):
        progBar['current'][0] = i
        for k in range(10):

            progBar['text'][1] = 'Inner Loop item %d' % k
            progBar['current'][1] = k
            #just print things to the terminal
            print('i: %d , k:%d, currTest: %s' % (i, k, progBar['text'][1]))

            time.sleep(.02)
    clear_prog_bar([0, 1])  #clear the progress bars that we used since we're done with them.
    print('finished')

def clear_prog_bar(index_list):
    global update_progBar
    for i in index_list:
        progBar['used'][i] = False
    if True not in progBar['used']:  # see if any prog bars are being used by something
        update_progBar = False


############################# Begin GUI code #############################
def the_gui():
    sg.theme('Light Brown 3')

    layout = [[sg.Text('Click Go to start a long-running function call')],
              [sg.Text(size=(25, 1), key='-OUTPUT0-')],
              [sg.Text(size=(25, 1), key='-OUTPUT1-')],
              [sg.Text(size=(25, 1), key='-OUTPUT2-')],
              [sg.ProgressBar(100, 'h', size=(30, 20), k='-PROGBAR0-')],
              [sg.ProgressBar(100, 'h', size=(30, 20), k='-PROGBAR1-')],
              [sg.ProgressBar(100, 'h', size=(30, 20), k='-PROGBAR2-')],
              [sg.Button('Go'), sg.Button('Popup'), sg.Button('Exit')], ]

    window = sg.Window('Multithreaded Window', layout)
    # --------------------- EVENT LOOP ---------------------


    while True:
        event, values = window.read()
        if event in (sg.WIN_CLOSED, 'Exit'):
            print('exiting...')
            break
        if event == 'Go':  # clicking "Go" starts a long running work item by starting thread
            print('adding thread')
            thread_id = threading.Thread(target=general_long_function, args=(), daemon=True)

            thread_id.start()
        if event == 'Popup':
            sg.popup_non_blocking('This is a popup showing that the GUI is running', grab_anywhere=True)

        if update_progBar:
            for i, used in enumerate(progBar['used']):
                if used:
                    window['-PROGBAR%d-' % i].update(progBar['current'][i], progBar['max'][i])
                    window['-OUTPUT%d-' % i].update(progBar['text'][i])

    window.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    the_gui()
    print('Exiting Program')
```

I'm hoping I can call one of several functions depending on what button the user presses, and then  have those run while the progress bar is being updated. I've seen several things to use the window.write_event_value function, but I think I would have to pass the window into the function, and update things from there... but if I'm using those same functions without a GUI, I would imagine that would cause some errors. Is what I'm trying to do easily done?

Edit: I notice that when I click the popup button it does update the progress bar a single time to whatever the current counts and such are... I'm not sure how or why it's updating those variables then, but it does it once, just not constantly.

Comment: I think there is an answer here: stackoverflow.com/a/60741258/5166365. Nevertheless, I'm not sure why your progress bar update fires only when you open the popup. My guess is its because you have no timeout specified in window.read(), but this is speculation. Either way, reading (but not writing) global variables from the UI event loop will not corrupt any data.

Comment: The execution of your main thread will be blocked at `window.read()`. When go `if update_progBar:` ? Only happened once when any event generated, like button `Go` or `Popup` clicked. To keep monitoring the state of your global variable and updating the progress bar, try to add option `timeout`, like `window.read(timeout=100)`, timeout too short or too long may work wrong.

Comment: the timeout was what I was missing, Thanks! if one of you would like to post that as an answer, I'll gladly accept it. thanks again for your help!